# vertical text height in css

Tags: css, text, alignment

How to fix the height of the vertical text? It is not working properly with `line-height or height` property

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/BsZ8f/1/

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/BsZ8f/2/) what you want??

Comment: But I dont want that left and right space for text

Comment: may be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/BsZ8f/6/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

I tried my hand on the code but couldn't figure out. My solution would be to use just css2 to create vertical text, for this you just need to give the .title a fixed width say 10px just enough to hold one character, this way the text will automatically get aligned vertically and give height: auto; overflow: auto; to make sure the height adjusts.

Comment: I gt the solution for this. Thanks anyway :)